# Call controller inside controler. Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I have a Login form that call a controler.

```
<form action="@{Application.callWS()}" method="post">
...
</form> 

public static void callWS(){
 //some logic
 if(true){
  renderTemplate("FOLDER1/FOLDER2/MY_View.html"); //call other page
 }
 else{
  renderTemplate("Application/index.html", error); // back to prev page with error variable
 }
}
```

If true I want call other page. But when I do renderTemplate() the url in my page still de same. "http://localhost:9000/application/callws"

I have a controler in `controllers/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/My_controller.java`. 
If true I want call index() from that controller and by doing that change the url to something related with that page.

in routes I have:

```
GET     /My_Page   FOLDER1/FOLDER2.My_controller.index
```

The question is: How can I call other page from first controller and change url to that page.

I am not using framework correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
controllers.FOLDER1.FOLDER2.My_controller.index
```

(not FOLDER/FOLDER2) as FOLDERs are mapped to java packages, which are separated by a dot (package1.subpackage.Class). Make sure your Controller has a package definition as its first statement:

```
package controllers.FOLDER1.FOLDER2;
```

This works to get your controller compiling:

```
controllers.FOLDER1.FOLDER2.My_controller.index();
```

as well as in your route file:

```
controllers.FOLDER1.FOLDER2.My_controller.index
```

Comment: Ok, my mistake. but I only can do that if I add controller before: controllers.FOLDER1.FOLDER2.My_controller.index(). I have to add controllers in package otherwise will show a error: The declared package "FOLDER1.FOLDER2" does not match the expected package "controllers.FOLDER1.FOLDER2".

Comment: Just edited the answer to fix yor case correctly. Does it work this way?

Comment: Yes, is working. The route file I'm not sure. The url show something like http://localhost:9000/FOLDER1.FOLDER2/MyMethod

Answer (score 3):

You should simply call the controller.

`MyController.myMethod()`

If you want to transmit messages or other information, (error message for example) you should use the flash scope:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#session

Comment: How can I call a method inside controllers/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/My_controller.java ? FOLDER1/FOLDER2/My_controller.myMethod() ? I am getting a error when I do that: could not be compiled. Error raised is :  FOLDER1/FOLDER2.My_controller cannot be resolved to a type